# Gracefully handling application exceptions in a Tornado application

Tags: tornado

Based on some googling I installed the following error handler. However the python exceptions which appear to return a http 500 are not trapped by this stuff, although 404's are. With the print statements I have left in the code below, I can see that it does not hit any of these routines. What should I really be doing?

```python
class ErrorHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
"""Generates an error response with status_code for all requests."""
def __init__ (self, application, request, status_code):
    print 'In ErrorHandler init'
    tornado.web.RequestHandler.__init__(self, application, request)
    self.set_status(status_code)

def get_error_html (self, status_code, **kwargs):
    print 'In get_error_html. status_code: ', status_code
    if status_code in [403, 404, 500, 503]:
        filename = '%d.html' % status_code
        print 'rendering filename: ', filename
        return self.render_string(filename, title=config.get_title())

    return "<html><title>%(code)d: %(message)s</title>" \
            "<body class='bodyErrorPage'>%(code)d: %(message)s</body>"\
            "</html>" % {
            "code": status_code,
            "message": httplib.responses[status_code],
            }

def prepare (self):
    print 'In prepare...'
    raise tornado.web.HTTPError(self._status_code)
```

Answer (score 15):

First of all, the exception that you are raising in `prepare` has code `200`, therefore it's not caught in the `get_error_html` function.

Secondly, `get_error_html` is deprecated: use `write_error`, instead ([write_error](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/web.html?highlight=write_error#tornado.web.RequestHandler.write_error)).

Finally, you don't need to call `__init__` on `ErrorHandler`: to initialize a handler use `initialize` ([initialize](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/web.html?highlight=write_error#tornado.web.RequestHandler.initialize)), but in this case you don't need it.

Here is a working example:

```python
import tornado
import tornado.web


class ErrorHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    """Generates an error response with status_code for all requests."""

    def write_error(self, status_code, **kwargs):
        print 'In get_error_html. status_code: ', status_code
        if status_code in [403, 404, 500, 503]:
            self.write('Error %s' % status_code)
        else:
            self.write('BOOM!')

    def prepare(self):
        print 'In prepare...'
        raise Exception('Error!')


application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", ErrorHandler),
        ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8899)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: Iboola, thank you for the response. By declaring a write_error() method for the hanlders I am able to trap the 500s; however this approach does not really work for handling the 404s across the site!

So I had to combine a global error handler class that I assigned to tornado.web.ErrorHandler, in addition to a base class with a write_error() method as suggested by you. Now I an able to catch my application exceptions, in addition to global 404s.

Comment: @Karra how did you managed to combine both general 500 error with the 404 error by app handler? Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

1. Handlers. Lets define some default handlers we gonna to use

```python
import tornado.web


class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    """
    Base handler gonna to be used instead of RequestHandler
    """
    def write_error(self, status_code, **kwargs):
        if status_code in [403, 404, 500, 503]:
            self.write('Error %s' % status_code)
        else:
            self.write('BOOM!')


class ErrorHandler(tornado.web.ErrorHandler, BaseHandler):
    """
    Default handler gonna to be used in case of 404 error
    """
    pass


class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    """
    Main handler
    """
    def get(self):
        self.write('Hello world!')
```

2. Settings. We need to define `default_handler_class` and `default_handler_args` as well

```python
settings = {
    'default_handler_class': ErrorHandler,
    'default_handler_args': dict(status_code=404)
}
```

3. Application.

```python
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler)
], **settings)
```

as result. all errors except 404 gonna be handled by BaseHandler. 404 - ErrorHandler. that's it :)

Answer (score -1):

```
import tornado.web


class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def write_error(self, status_code, **kwargs):
        print status_code
        super(BaseHandler, self).write_error(status_code, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Please add some context, explanation or any relevant comment instead of just contextless code.