# Error Handling in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I'm new to Tornado and writing a basic application but also need to add Error handling. Below is the code.

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web

from tornado import gen
from tornado.web import asynchronous
from tornado.options import define, options

define("port", default=8888, help="run on the given port", type=int)

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", HomeHandler),
            (r"/mycompany", myCustomHandler),
            (r"/mycompany/", myCustomHandler),
        ]
        super(Application, self).__init__(handlers)

class HomeHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
                self.render("home.html")

class myCustom(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
                self.write("Processing....")
                self.clear()
                self.finish()

def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The home.html works fine.

Next, I would like users to pass parameters using format something like http://host:port/mycompany/?id=9999.

But want to display a 404 PAGE when somebody enters *host:port/blahblah or *host:port/mycompany/?something=9999. How do I go about doing that?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gracefully handling application exceptions in a Tornado application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392952/gracefully-handling-application-exceptions-in-a-tornado-application)

Answer (score 1):

To use a custom error page for unknown URLs, use the `default_handler_class` argument to `Application()`. Errors raised *within* a handler use the `write_error` method to produce error pages. Using the same error handling for both is a little complicated; here's the basic scaffolding:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def write_error(self, status_code, **kwargs):
        if status_code == 404:
            self.render("404.html")
        else:
            self.render("error.html")

class My404Handler(BaseHandler):
    def prepare(self):
        raise tornado.web.HTTPError(404)

class MyCustomHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if not self.valid_arguments():
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(400)

app = Application([...], default_handler_class=My404Handler)
```